# Why does the content appear completely outside the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a script [from this library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-sort.html) to display a table. When I tested it in simple body element **it rendered perfectly fine**. [Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9J8yy/)

*But I want to display the table inside a div in the following code (inside the leftdiv) but it renders outside all the div's.* **How can I fix this?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="yui3-skin-sam">
        <div id="leftrightwrapper" style="background-color:brown; width:1180px; height:650px;"> <!-- start leftrightwrapper -->

        <div id="leftwrapper" style="width:590px; float:left; background-color:grey; overflow-y:auto;  height:650px;" class="yui3-skin-sam"> <!--start leftwrapper-->
            <div >
                <script>
                    YUI().use("datatable-sort", function(Y) {
                    var cols = [
                        {key:"Company", label:"Sort Column A", sortable:true},
                        {key:"Phone", label:"Sort Column B", sortable:true},
                        {key:"Contact", label:"Sort Column C", sortable:true}
                    ],
                    data = [
                        {Company:"Company Bee", Phone:"415-555-1234", Contact:"Sally Spencer"},
                        {Company:"Acme Company", Phone:"650-555-4444", Contact:"John Jones"},
                        {Company:"Industrial Industries", Phone:"408-555-5678", Contact:"Robin Smith"}
                    ],
                    table = new Y.DataTable({
                        columns: cols,
                        data   : data,
                        summary: "Contacts list",
                        caption: "Table with simple column sorting"
                    }).render("#sort");
                    });
                </script>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end leftwrapper -->

        <div id="rightwrapper" style="width:590px; float:right; background-color:pink;  overflow-y:auto;  height:650px;" >
            <!-- contents of rightdiv -->
        </div> <!-- end rightdiv -->

        </div> <!-- end leftrightwrapper -->




    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you got a space at the end of the first div tag before the table - it reads    <div >

Comment: @user2356315 You mean the problem is `<div >` written instead of `<div>`? So what does that space character have to do with this? =o

Comment: Immediately before the table <script> tag.

Comment: @user2356315 `<div >` *is* valid, even though it looks ugly. The number of spaces before the closing token (`>` or `/>`) don't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the desired `<div/>` the ID `sort`

The table will not be rendered where you place the script, it will be rendered in the element that will be supplied as argument to `render`

```
.render("#sort");
```

...so there must be an element that matches the selector(currently there isn't such an element in the page, so it will be rendered to the body)

of course you may also change the argument of `render` to `#leftwrapper` and use the current ID

http://jsfiddle.net/9J8yy/2/